# OneToOne bidirectional relationship with the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with the definition of the `OneToOne` bidirectional relationship with the same entity.

In particular, I defined a class `User` and I wanted to give it an attribute `partner`, that is a `User` itself.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Long ID;

    ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_partners",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "u1", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "u2", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private User partner;

    ...
}
```

Now, if I test this case defined in my repository `UserRepository.java`:

```java
...
User um = new User(...);
User uf = new User(...);

um.setPartner(uf);
...
```

I would expect that both `um` and `uf` have the reference to their partner. Instead, only `um` has the reference as I explicitly defined it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You defined a unidirectional association. If it was bidirectional you'd have a second ManyToMany, with a mappedBy, and a name such as isPartnerOf. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Why ManyToMany? I wanted a OneToOne relationship, meaning that a User can have a single partner and vice versa... Is that possible?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant OneToOne. Still the same issue though. Take a User and a Phone. For a bidirectional association, you have a OneToOne in User, and a second one in Phone. A user has a phne, and a phone has an owner. You need the same here: two fields, two OneToOne annotations. Otherwise you have a unidirectional association, not a bidirectional one.

Comment: Ok, but then I would have the second user having a `partnerOf` and not a `partner`, correct? Isn't there a clearer way? And also, is that even possible with this configuration to add a constraint like "if a user has a partner, he cannot be a partner to anyone else"?
Thanks a lot for your time!